# Netsuite - Add Dynamic Number of Records to a Custom Record?

Tags: netsuite, sublist

I'm trying to figure out how to add a dynamic number of custom records to another custom record.

Basically, we have test result remarks that should be related to a test record. They can have any number of these remarks, but I can't figure out how to do that in Netsuite. I was thinking of adding a sublist, but it doesn't look like I am able to do this. I am VERY new to netsuite, so I apologize if this is really easy and I am just missing something, but can someone point me in the right direction?

I basically want it to be pretty easy to add records (was thinking of a sublist with inline editing where they can just add as many new defect record to the test as required. There are 4 pieces of information that need to be added for each defect. I created a separate Defect custom record. I want the user to be able to relate the test to the defect record, and to be able to add the defects pretty easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your detail custom record

- create a List/Record custom field.
- make the list the parent custom record
- check "Record is Parent"

After you save it you'd go to each test result remarks and select the appropriate test record. If you add them via the UI to the test record this will be done automatically. If you have a bunch of existing records and know which test record they belong to you can link those up via a script or csv import.

Netsuite actually works pretty well for this.

Comment: Is there not a quick/easy way to add them FROM the test record? Like you would add items to a purchase order?

Comment: okay, I found where it goes after I create the first one, then it is pretty easy to add more after that, but is there a way to make adding that first result easy? Or always showing that custom tab to add a new result?

Comment: Yes. Customize the form so that the custom tab of the parent form is the first in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a *Test* custom record and a *Test Result* custom record.

On your *Test Result* custom record definition, add a field of type `List/Record` and Record Type `Test`.

On that field's definition, check `Record is Parent`.

Then as instances of *Test Result* records are created, set their parent *Test* record appropriately in that field. This will automatically add a sublist of *Test Results* to *Test* records.

Comment: Is there not a quick/easy way to add them FROM the test record? Like you would add items to a purchase order? –

Comment: okay, I found where it goes after I create the first one, then it is pretty easy to add more after that, but is there a way to make adding that first result easy? Or always showing that custom tab to add a new result?

Comment: Looks like I just have to save it, and then I can add results. Thanks!

Comment: You got it! Glad it helped.